# Java subString and indexOf

Tags: java, string, substring

I have been given the following question.

```
String string1 = "The ice cold ice-cream";
String string2 = "phone";
String string3 = "";
int p = string1.indexOf("ice",8);
string3 = string1.substring(0, p + 1);
string3 = string3 + string2.toUpperCase();
```

I cannot seem to get the second and third value.

The substring and `int p` has really got me confused.

Could anyone help with the answer and also explain how to work this out.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of value expecting for second & Third?

Comment: @Masud: the second and third value of string3.

Comment: @mike yaworski: the code doesn't output anything - the question was what are the values for string3 at the various points in the code.

Comment: It's very easy to test this by simply printing out the value of `string3` each time after you change it. If you were confused by what was happening, you could simply Google the `.subtring(int,int)` method for Java, as well as the `.indexOf(String, int)` method for Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first value of string3 is an empty string.

Now p is the index of "ice" in string1 occurring after the 8th index. So p is 13 (you can count it yourself).

The second value of string3 is string1 taken from the 0th index to the (13+1)th index. Or string1 from 0 to the 14th index. That comes out to be

```
"The ice cold i" // note the 14th index is not included
```

Finally, the third value of string3 is whatever string3 was earlier plus string2 in uppercase letters. Which is

```
"The ice cold i" + "PHONE" or simply "The ice cold iPHONE"
```

If you are having trouble with String methods, you should check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html